Is believing that an object that you’re staring at won’t suddenly pop out of existence justifiable or unjustifiable?
For example, say you are sitting at a desk with a plastic water bottle upon it. You set a timer for 30 seconds and stare at the water bottle. As you are setting the timer, you say to yourself “It is guaranteed that this plastic water bottle won’t pop out of existence in these 30 seconds that I’m staring at it.” Is such a statement justifiable?
Now, the only justification I can come up with is that we have never in our lives seen any object just pop out of existence, but obviously Hume and the problem of induction showed us that this is not a valid justification.
Your thoughts?

It is a prediction and you can test it waiting 30 seconds. The result can be used to check the "method" used to formulate it.

The sad truth is that we won't really know what the future holds until it becomes the past, according to my Philosophy professor.

It depends on the (putative) plastic. Replace “plastic bottle” by “cloud" or “soap bubble” and it doesn't seem so absurd does it? If you want a more nuanced answer, interpolate from the tables here

Better drink more water than stare at it.

It is a justification, simply not a proof like one you could have in math or formal logic. If we stopped relying on induction we would just starve and die. After all, there is no justification for believing that food is necessary for survival...

It is justifiable to believe an object will not pop out of existence (or perception, as pointed out elsewhere), but you may not be right about it.
Because we can verify our belief against the experiences of ourselves and most other people in the world, it's a justifiable belief to hold that the object will remain in our perceptive field after just 30 seconds.
That said, it's not to say that it's necessarily a true belief. Something may indeed happen to the object depending on what material it's made out of, environmental circumstances, etc. that could cause it to 'not exist' in the same manner that it did when you started looking at it.

The Sock-Dryer Enigma comes to mind. Socks have popped out of existence in my dryer. I have heard others have had the same experience.

Don't stare at atomic bombs to see if they will pop out of existence. They just might.

What, precisely, do you mean by justify?

In this context, I consider a justifiable belief to be one that is reliable; Something you can count on in most circumstances.

It would not "pop out of existence" but "out of perception" (which to some are the same thing). Some stage magicians are able to pull off such psychological tricks.
And of course, if the object never existed in the first place, it will pop away. I (and many others) experienced such phenomena in childhood, such as a ghost/demon invoked by fears and shadows and poor lighting, that vanished when I was grounded.
In one particular case I was confronted by a giant bat in the school library, about a metre tall, swaying from side to side. After an eternity the chaplain, who had been bent over a lower bookshelf, and who was wearing a creased black gown, stood upright.
I've been aware of this phenomenon when listening and reading too, when my mind predicts how the meaning will unfold, and auto-corrects as it happens. But sometimes, I am sure that a false interpretation may persist if I am distracted before the confusion has been resolved.
So let your bottle vanish – if it was an illusion. There is a great difference between perception and reality... which we can never quite reach.

It just comes down to how you want to define the concept of impossiblity.
One could take the position that the word is fairly useless because, being imperfect beings capable of error, we can never justifiably deem something "impossible".
One could take the position that only true logical impossibilities can be known to us imperfect beings. Perhaps we can know that something cannot both possibly have a property and not have a property at the same time and to the same extent, but not much else.
But we do in fact also label as "impossible" things that are truly inconsistent with our understanding of cause and effect. Unless you believe that we can deem nothing impossible or only deem that which is self-contradictory to be impossible, the concept extends to that which we justifiably believe to be physically impossible because it is inconsistent with physical laws we justifiably believe not to have exceptions.

Is believing that an object that you’re staring at won’t suddenly pop out of existence justifiable or unjustifiable?

Belief would not be a useful concept if we set such a high threshold for belief that we couldn't function in our daily lives. The amount of evidence or argument we need to support a belief is not really that high.
If Jeff tells me that he missed work yesterday because he was sick, I have no reason not to believe him, and I do believe him, then that belief is justified. Of course, I do accept that it could be wrong and I would be wise not to forget how strong and weak the evidence I have to support that belief is in case I encounter additional evidence later.

I don't think believing in something is the same as thinking its converse impossible, so I guess it first comes down to how you want to define "believe".

@JohnBollinger I generally define believe as "subjectively committed (whether weakly or strongly) to the truth of a proposition". Certainly we are justified in subjectively committing to the truth of a proposition to at least the extent we are subejctively committed to the impossibility of its converse.

Sure, I accept that if I think it impossible for some proposition to be true, then it's reasonable to say that I believe its converse to be true.  But my point is that that doesn't go the other way.  I can and do believe a wide variety of things that I know might not actually be true -- it is possible that their converses are true instead.  This answer seems to acknowledge that that's reasonable and pragmatic, so I'm still not following how the leading discussion about impossibility speaks to the question.

Then I'm not sure I understand what your original comment was trying to say. I don't think there's any controversy about what it means to "believe" something -- it's a subjective committment that it is true. We justifiably form these if we have some evidence that something is true and no particular reason to think it's not true. The strength of the believe depends on the strength of the evidence. Here, the evidence is so strong, we justfifiably believe the converse impossible.

The point of the original comment is that it does not at all come down to the definition of impossibility, contrary to the first part of this answer, unless one defines "believe" differently than than we seem to agree it should be defined.

@JohnBollinger Unless your argument is that showing something is impossible doesn't show we are justified in believing the converse, I don't know what your argument is.

My argument is that believing something to be true does not require believing its converse to be impossible. The latter is a stronger condition, which it is neither necessary nor particularly helpful to invoke in response to the question posed.  As far as I can tell, the first four paragraphs of this answer would be improved by reducing them to "It is justified to believe that we will not observe behavior inconsistent with physical laws."

@JohnBollinger It's true that I could have made a weaker argument than I made. But generally, it's good to make the strongest argument that you possibly can, and that's what I chose to do. The problem with making the weaker argument you suggest is that it's vulnerable to immediate follow up questions that you would need the stronger argument to rebut anyway.

By using the stronger condition, you have not made a stronger argument, but rather a narrower one.  To wit: provided that we believe it impossible to observe behavior inconsistent with physical laws, it is justified to believe that we will not observe behavior inconsistent with physical laws.  That's open to substantially all the same followups as the version I offered, just couched in terms of what the proviso means and whether to accept it.

@JohnBollinger I don't agree. The key difference is that my argument shows not just that we are justified in believing that objects will not pop out of existence but that we are justified in believing they can not pop out of existence. If the followups are the same, better to get the much stronger point out of them.

Well, no. The argument has the form "if condition then conclusion".  That is categorically weaker than just conclusion. The former is perhaps more explanatory, and perhaps easier to justify, but it does not provide any basis for accepting condition.

I assume OP is not asking about any kind of illusion, trick, magic, illness of the mind (psychosis etc.) but is specifically creating an experiment which is as everyday as possible. I.e., an experiment we witness with exactly the same result every day, everywhere around us: macroscopic objects do not usually spontaneously disappear, and if they do so, there is nearly always a plausible reason that is obvious. We are not talking about special cases like a magician's illusion, or some complex machinery whisking some object away so quickly that our brains cannot see it, or an optical illusion. Quite obviously he is not asking about a case where some person suddenly jumps up from behind his desk and takes the bottle away, or where the Sun suddenly goes supernova and obliterates the bottle. By design we are also talking about an event which is not a 75%/25% chance, but incredibly closer to (but of course never completely at) 100%/0%.
He is specifically formulating it as pop out of existence. Not "take away", "be gone after the 30s", "fallen off the table", "destroyed" or anything like that. Even the formulation of "pop out of existence" clearly invites the thought that this simply does not happen in our everyday experience.
So in the spirit of this assumption...
It is absolutely justifiable to assume that the object behaves as usual, in many variations of what "justified" could mean. Quoting SEP's entry on Justified True Belief, and checking which dimensions they have of different views regarding this:

Internalists beliefe it would be justified: "if and only if believing that p is the attitude towards p that best fits S’s evidence, where the latter is understood to depend only on S’s internal mental states" (the evidence, after many experiments and including S's mental state, speaks for the expectation).
Externalists do as well: "for example, process reliabilists think that justified beliefs are those which are formed by a cognitive process which tends to produce a high proportion of true beliefs relative to false ones" thinking it through, it is much more likely that a process view leads to the bottle still being there. Otherwise you'd need a process that somehow changes the result, and arguably the way the argument is set up, the everyday process seems most likely.
Propositional justification "concerns whether a subject has sufficient reason to believe a given proposition" and certainly applies here, and...
... doxastic justification concerns whether a given belief is held "appropriately", and surely matches as well.

So while nothing is ever certain, and while it may be worthwhile to point OP to the Bayesian Epistemology/worldview, it seems abundantly clear that it is unnecessary to make OP's example more complicated than it is: it is justifiable to believe that the object will behave like it always does; exceptions notwithstanding.
Whether it is also true belief does not matter. OP is asking about justified belief, not full JTB knowledge here.

I'd be willing to bet you $1000 at 10-1 odds that it won't pop out of existence. The problem of induction says we can't prove it won't, but that doesn't mean we can't say which outcome is more likely. We can argue the semantics of what exactly constitutes a justified belief, but we know that in practice, if you accepted bets like that, I'd be the one to come out ahead. This provides us a very practical definition of "justified" under which the belief is quite well justified indeed.
